# org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

**This is my entity class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sofort_payment")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Accessors(chain = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
public class SofortPaymentEntity extends BasicEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;
    @Column(name = "referenced_transaction")
    private UUID referencedTransaction;
    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
    @Column(name = "reason")
    private String reason;
    @Column(name = "external_payment_id")
    private String externalPaymentId;
    @Column(name = "currency")
    private String currency;
    @Column(name = "amount")
    private BigDecimal amount;
    @Column(name = "iban")
    private String iban;
    @Column(name = "back_name")
    private String bankName;
    @Column(name = "sender_holder")
    private String senderHolder;
    @Column(name = "bic")
    private String bic;
    @Column(name = "bank_code")
    private String bankCode;
    @Column(name = "country_code")
    private String countryCode;

}
```

**My basic Entity class**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public abstract class BasicEntity {
  @Column(name = "created_at")
  @CreationTimestamp
  private LocalDateTime createdAt;
  @Column(name = "updated_at")
  @UpdateTimestamp
  private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

**My table structure :**

```
create table sofort_payment
(
    id                          UUID         NOT NULL
        constraint sofort_payment_pkey primary key,
    referenced_transaction      UUID references transaction(id) NOT NULL,
    status                      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      reason                      text,
    external_payment_id         varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    currency                    varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    amount                      numeric(19, 2) NOT NULL,
      iban                        varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      back_name                   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    sender_holder               varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    bic                         varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    bank_code                   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    country_code                varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at                  timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at                  timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
);
```

but when I try to print the SofortPaymentEntity it does not print the crated_dt and update_dt and when I try to update it throws the following exception. This table already has the entry which means that it is created first and now I am trying to update it

```
sofortPaymentRepository.save(sofortPaymentEntity.builder()
                                                 .id(sofortPaymentEntity.getId())
                                                 .referencedTransaction(sofortPaymentEntity.getReferencedTransaction())
                                                 .externalPaymentId(statusNotification.getTransId())
                                                 .amount(BigDecimal.valueOf(paymentTransactionDetails.getAmount()))
                                                 .currency(paymentTransactionDetails.getCurrencyCode())
                                                 .reason(paymentTransactionDetails.getStatusReason().toString())
                                                 .bankCode(paymentTransactionDetails.getSender().getBankCode())
                                                 .bankName(paymentTransactionDetails.getSender().getBankName())
                                                 .bic(paymentTransactionDetails.getSender().getBic())
                                                 .iban(paymentTransactionDetails.getSender().getIban())
                                                 .countryCode(paymentTransactionDetails.getSender().getCountryCode())
                                                 .senderHolder(paymentTransactionDetails.getSender().getHolder())
                                                 .status(paymentTransactionDetails.getStatus().toString()).build());
```

**ERROR**:

```
null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint
```

**Generic exception caught**:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; 
constraint [created_at]; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:296)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:534)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:305)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:138)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
```

Comment: The issue is you are setting null created_at. It's not null constraint.

Comment: Actually i am not setting it. The code is automatically doing it. It should automatically update it right?

Comment: @VinayaNayak How can you be so sure that code is setting `created_at`?

Answer (score 0):

give a default timestamp value when creating the table like

```
created_at timestamp without time zone default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
```

or set the columnDefinition property for @Column annotation specific to database provider and use @Temporal.  ex psql:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private java.util.Date createdAt
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same DataIntegerityVoilation error because I was violating length property of a column in Entity.

```
@Column(name= "trade_id", length = 20, nullable = false)
private tradeId;
```

So, you cannot enter tradeId of length more than 20.

Answer (score -1):

That's a SQL syntax problem. Review your model class configuration or if data is ok about the database.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).